# How to validate usernames using matches(regex)?

Tags: regex, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm trying to put the following expression into the matches function but I guess errors when trying to compile the rules.

```
 ^[a-zA-Z](([\._\-][a-zA-Z0-9])|[a-zA-Z0-9])*[a-z0-9]$
```

`.validate` rule looks as follows:

```
".validate": "newData.val() === auth.uid         
&& newData.val().matches(^(?=.{5,10}$)(?!.*[._-]{2})[a-z][a-z0-9._-]*[a-z0-9]$)"
```

I get:

```
" Invalid escape: '\.'"
```

Comment: matches(/^(?=.{5,10}$)(?!.*[._-]{2})[a-z][a-z0-9._-]*[a-z0-9]$/)

Comment: @Pawan still getting the same error.

Comment: @SalmanAA matches as a rule in Firebase?

Comment: you need to use \\ . instead of \. and \\- istead of \-,  check the doc if it helps https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-validate

Comment: Try `.matches(/^(?=.{5,10}$)(?!.*[._-]{2})[a-z][a-z0-9._-]*[a-z0-9]$/)` - not sure about the use of uppercase and lowercase letters, your two patterns differ.

Comment: When entering regular expressions in Firebase security rules, you'll need to escape the backslashes. So `^[a-zA-Z](([\\._\\-][a-zA-Z0-9])|[a-zA-Z0-9])*[a-z0-9]$`

Comment: The point is that you do not have to escape the hyphen and dot in your current expression.

Comment: @Relm, did you have time to check the patterns here, in comments?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes Thanks, probably the problem was firebase Specific. Check out **Frank van Puffelen's** comment. So it ended up being            `.matches(/^[a-zA-Z](([\\._\\-][a-zA-Z0-9])|[a-zA-Z0-9])*[a-z0-9]$/)`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen only realising now that you cut off the first part of my expression that regulates min and max length, or is it because you think it will be easier doing this with **Firebase's** `newData.val().length` ?

Comment: Do you mean double escaping? But you do not have to escape any single char inside `[._-]`. If your pattern works without llength restriction, it means firebase does not support lookarounds.  Then use the second step to check length as you suggested.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew will use the second step. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you cannot use lookarounds in Firebase, so your pattern and the whole approach should be adjusted to account for that.

Your current regex requires a string length from 5 to 10 symbols, and disallows 2 consecutive symbols `.`, `_` and `-`. The first condition should be checked outside the regex with some code like `newData.val().length >= 5 && newData.val().length <= 10` and the second one just requires re-grouping and re-quantifying:

```
.matches(/^[a-z][a-z0-9]*([._-][a-z0-9]+)*$/)
```

See the regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uR5eC0/1).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-z]` - a lowercase letter (if you add `/i` at the end, it will be case sensitive)
- `[a-z0-9]*` - zero or more `a-z` and `0-9` symbols
- `([._-][a-z0-9]+)*` - a `.`, `_` or `-` followed with *one or more* (this requires `[a-z0-9]` to be at the end if there is `.`, `_` or `-` in the string) characters from `0-9` and `a-z` ranges
- `$` - the end of string anchor.

Note you do not need to escape the characters inside the character class as the `.` and `_` are not special chars inside it, and the `-` at the end or start of the bracket expression (character class) is  a literal hyphen.

Comment: While Frank's pattern `^[a-zA-Z](([\\._\\-][a-zA-Z0-9])|[a-zA-Z0-9])*[a-z0-9]$` seems correct, it involves much more backtracking, while mine is more linear and follows the [unroll-the-loop principle](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop).